# Admob Crashing App when final Ads are implemented - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, admob, banner, banner-ads

Trying to implement AdMob on my iOS/SwiftUI app. Chose the BannerAd style, implemented it in a few screens. Have been using the test ads, as per admob guidelines, for a while, with no issues. However, now that I want to implement the real ads and I change the unitID for the AdMob key, my app crashes in Testflight. This is weird, because it works in XCode's test devices and my device in test mode. When I search the internet, most solutions are either for Android or Interstitial Ads...

**Banner Ad Backend**

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMobileAds

struct BannerAd: UIViewRepresentable {
    var unitID: String
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GADBannerView{
        let adView = GADBannerView(adSize: GADAdSizeBanner)
        adView.adUnitID = unitID
        adView.rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.getRootViewController()
        adView.delegate = context.coordinator
        adView.load(GADRequest())
        return adView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: GADBannerView, context: Context) {
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject,GADBannerViewDelegate{
        func bannerViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
          print("bannerViewDidReceiveAd")
        }

        func bannerView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error) {
          print("bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        func bannerViewDidRecordImpression(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
          print("bannerViewDidRecordImpression")
        }

        func bannerViewWillPresentScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
          print("bannerViewWillPresentScreen")
        }

        func bannerViewWillDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
          print("bannerViewWillDIsmissScreen")
        }

        func bannerViewDidDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
          print("bannerViewDidDismissScreen")
        }
    }
    
}
extension UIApplication{
    func getRootViewController()->UIViewController{
        guard let screen = self.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else{
            return .init()
        }
        
        guard let root = screen.windows.first?.rootViewController else{
            return .init()
        }
        
        return root
    }
}
```

**The Banner Ad implementation Example:**

```
import SwiftUI
import MessageUI
import AppTrackingTransparency

struct PatientsView: View {
    
    [...]   
            ScrollView(){
            BannerAd(unitID: "ca-app-pub-numbers")
                    .frame(maxHeight: 50)
                VStack(alignment:.leading){
                    [...]
                }
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.top, 30.0)
            }
        
        }
}
```

Comment: `getRootViewController` could be a contributor use a custom `UIViewController` with `UIViewControllerReprsentable` any solution that uses the root is problematic.

Comment: Changed the approach to something using this, still the same issue

Comment: What is crashing? What is the error?

Comment: Looks like we are using the same code. Mine works ok. My problem is when loading the banner, the height is too big, it becomes an inline adaptive banner somewhat. But before the .load() is called, the adSize values of width and height are correct. But after load request, its height becomes bigger instead of 50.